# Проблема с русскими символами в bat при отправке на FTP.

Tags: windows, ftp, bat

Есть некий bat файл следующего содержания:

```
ftp -s:"%appdata%\param.txt" xx.xx.xxx.xx
```

Как понятно, данная строчка производит соединение к FTP серверу, исходя из параметров, находящихся в этом файле `%appdata%\param.txt`. %appdata% - переменная среды, зависящая от версии Windows. Данная переменная содержит имя папки текущего пользователя, например,

```
C:\Users\ЯЮЗЕР\AppData\Roaming
```

Вот в чем у меня возникла проблема: в файле параметров соединения (`%appdata%\param.txt` ) к FTP содержится приблизительно такая информация:

```
username
pass
...
mput "%appdata%\Opera\Opera\wand_%arr%.dat"  // ошибка, если есть русские символы!!!
...
```

Файл не передается на FTP, если в имени пользователя есть русские символы, да и не только имени, **а вообще во всем пути %appdata%**! А они есть в 99% случаях! Как это исправить, ребят? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Пробовал через установку кодировки консоли `chcp 1251(866 и 65001)` ,  **но не получилось...**

---

**P.S**

[@karmadro4](/users/6679/karmadro4), надеюсь в первую очередь на Вас =).

Comment: А просто, руками набранный в FTP такой path идет ?

Comment: @avp, нет! Представляете, даже если руками набрать путь, содержащий русский текст( тестировал в cp 866, 1251, 65001 ), то все равно - ничего. Может с в самом FTP клиенте проблема?

Comment: Если ручками тоже не пересылает, то либо в клиенте либо в сервере. Попробйте с другого клиента (не Windows). Тогда станет более определенно.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать пути в формате 8.3. ``dir /x`` или ``dir /-n``

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вряд ли это будет правильным выходом...

Comment: @Dexter в смысле? У вас используется "причудливый" ftp клиент, который не работает с русскими символами. Либо меняйте клиент, либо попытайтесь ему угодить.

Comment: А пробовали файл перевести в другую кодировку?

Comment: @Dex, Вы имеете в виду path ? А что, взять и транслитерировать.

Comment: @avp, нет, зачем же? Просто человек пишет, что пробовал использовать разные кодировки в консоли, но файл-то оставался в той же кодировке, что и был, соответственно и символы отправлялись не те, что нужно.

Comment: @Dex, тут не в файле дело, так как если все "ввести ручками", то результат не меняется...

---
@Yura Ivanov, у меня штатный виндовый FTP клиент.

Comment: @Dexter, а на какой-нибудь другой FTP сервер этот клиент файлы с русскими буквами в имени посылает ?

Comment: В данном случае надо пользоваться штатным набором утилит "из коробки", поэтому юзать другой FTP коиент - нельзя.

Comment: Увы, на всех моих железках FTP искоренен уже более 5 лет на зад (действительно, ну его в зад!)

Answer (score 1):

Вы так и не сказали, какая ошибка выводится. Ошибка с кодировкой решается довольно успешно.

- Было:

  ```
  chcp 866
  ...
  ftp> mput c:\тест\тест.txt
  c:\тест\тест.txt:File not found
  ```
- Стало:

  ```
  chcp 1251
  ...
  ftp> mput c:\тест\тест.TXT
  mput c:\тест\тест.txt? y
  200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
  150 Ok to send data.
  226 Transfer complete.
  ftp: 4 bytes sent in 0,01Seconds 0,67Kbytes/sec.
  ```

Comment: Нет, не помогает! Говорю же, что на всех трех локалях безрезультатно.

Comment: На самом деле ошибка с %appdata% у меня воспроизводится и без русских букв в путях. Видимо ftp.exe не умеет использовать переменные среды... В этом проблема? попробуйте мой тест, без %appdata%.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо, но это тоже не помогает - пробовал разместить файл с русскими буквами в корне локального диска - не получилось.

Comment: тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой, полный путь работает, а %appdata% нет.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, почему у тебя не получается, у меня тоже была такая проблема. Решил "кавычками" - 
`open *****
USER ***** *****
quote PASV
cd htdocs/nnv/130/
send "D:\Подпапка\Сам файл.doc"
quit`

Заметил также, что файлы могут не отправляться, даже, если в названии папки или файла на английском языке стоит пробел. Как с другими символами - не знаю, про пробел точно уверен!